# step by step in-app IOS purchase-confused

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I have an IOS app in the app store. My plan is to make it free, and create an in-app purchase of a non-consumable product within it.
I have included some, but not all, of the in-app code needed to do this. I have uploaded the resulting builds to iTunes Connect without a problem.
To test the code I have created a test user in the 'sandbox'. I have logged out of my 'real' Apple ID (iCloud etc) in my iPhone and logged into the sandbox account...
and this is the point where I am confused...
When I click on the icon for my app, am I seeing its latest build, or the 'ready for sale' version. Do I have to anything? Is the Sandbox looking at my latest build or at the 'ready for sale' version?
BTW, I'm using Phobegap Build. 
Do I have to submit the app for review to Apple before I'm able to see the app in the Sandbox?
If it passes the review, does that then mean it becomes the 'ready for sale' version? If so, how do I develop the code efficiently if I have to resubmit each time? My first submit is going to contain errors... do I have to submit a 'perfect' working version before I continue development (which clearly doesn't make sense!).
As you can see I'm confused. The online help that I've found online is really helpful (especially Stack Overflow... thank you everyone), but 'big-picture' advice is elusive.

Comment: Normally you would plug your phone into your Mac and install development versions directly onto it. You can also use the TestFlight app to install versions that you have uploaded but not submitted yet. This would be a much slower process than continually installing development builds

Comment: TestFlight!... thank you... it didn't occur to me! :-(

Comment: I am using Phonegap to develop... can I install an .ipa that phonegap produces directly into an iphone that's plugged into the Mac? And thank you again!